# Unit test parallel programing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parallel.foreach

I have a tool which executes various tasks simulatiously.

The code looks like this:

```
while (true)
{
    tasks.ForEachWithIndex((item, index) =>
    {
        if (tasksToExecute[index] == null || tasksToExecute[index].ShouldRerun())
        { tasksToExecute[index] = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNewRecurring(() => ScheduledTaskHelper.ExecutePlatformTask(logWriter, uow, item)); }
    });

    // The tasks have been added to the factory, so let's start them now.
    var handleTaskCompletionTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAny(tasksToExecute.ToArray()).ContinueWith(
        (completedTask, o) =>
        {
            var taskId = completedTask.Result.Id;
            tasksToExecute.Find(x => x.Id == taskId).Rerun(true);
        }, null);

    try { handleTaskCompletionTask.Wait(); }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Note: I will not post all the implementation detail because this will take us to much.

Let's assume that I have 2 tasks, then the system takes the 2 tasks and processes them in parallel. When one of the task is finished it's reprocessed again by adding it to the parallel loop.

But now I'm struggling on how to unit test this implementation.
I was thinking about the following approach:

Create 2 tasks:

- 1 tasks that runs for 30 seconds.
- 1 task that runs for 5 seconds.

Checks that after 1 second, both tasks have the status IsRunning.
Checks that after 15 seconds, still both tasks have the status IsRunning.

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? you dont know which unit tests to write?

Comment: I do know what I want to write. I want to check that all tasks have the status IsRunning after a specified amount of time. So what I mean is, even when a task is completed, it needs to be picked up again. But I don't know how I can translate this into a single unit test.

Comment: As you can't re-run tasks, How would you check a task is "re-run"? once the re-run method executes, it will create a new task and the old one will be in a completed state, hence your "outer" reference will be obsolete?

Comment: So what do you propose than for making this unit testable? Perhapse using threads instead of tasks or is that a bad approach?